# Add plots directly to a document using python package docx

Tags: python, matplotlib, docx, python-docx

I am plotting some data and I want to automatically generate a report. I can save the plot and then add it to my document. However, I prefer to do it directly, without saving step. Going through the python-docx documentation I doubt it is doable by this package. Is there another way?

My code looks like this right now

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.savefig('test.png')

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Report',0)
document.add_picture('test.png', width=Inches(1.25))

document.save('report.docx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use StringIO :

> This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and
>   writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

memfile = StringIO()
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.savefig(memfile)

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Report',0)
document.add_picture(memfile, width=Inches(1.25))

document.save('report.docx')
memfile.close()
```

Python 3 : https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Python 2 : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Or use StringIO from `pandas.compat`

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with io. It is strange though that I get the error "TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'" when using Pandas. I would prefer to use pandas!

Comment: I would prefer io if you use python3 as it is standard

Comment: @Laleh did you find a better solution for your issue ? I'm curious to read alternative answers if you did !

Comment: the proposed solution works for me with but not with StringIO from Pandas. I had to do this: from io import BytesIO , memfile = BytesIO(). The rest is the same. I hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 7):

Try the code below in python 3 to directly save the plot in document.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import BytesIO

memfile = BytesIO()
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.savefig(memfile)

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Report',0)
document.add_picture(memfile, width=Inches(1.25))

document.save('report.docx')
memfile.close()
```

Comment: Try this if you are using python3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`docxtpl`](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template) and use `jinja` templates to place your charts.